# SweetAlert2 - how to store value input into field and hit enter

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2, agilepoint

recently i've tried to store input value of popup windows to text field area. i've succeed to store it from the popup input window but i want it to store it and then hit 'enter' automatically.

the popup asks from the user to input ID and then it store in specific text field and it needs to hit 'enter' to "update" the field.

[image]

This is the field and i want to function the sweetalert popup window to hit 'enter' after it stores the 123123 value in the text field.

this is the code:

```
function IDpopup () 
{ 
    Swal.fire({
    //rtl:true,
title: 'טופס בקשת הלוואה',
 html:' <p>שלום רב, בטופס זה ניתן להגיש בקשה לקבלת הלוואה מכל הסוגים. אולם, זכאות לקבלת הלוואה משתנה מעובד לעובד בהתאם לחוזים ובהתאם לותק. נא לשים לב.</p>'
 ,
 

  icon: 'info',
  width:'900px',
 input: 'text',
 inputLabel: 'תחילה, הזן מספר תעודת זהות:',
 inputPlaceholder: ':מספר תעודת הזהות'
}).then((inputValue) => {
    document.getElementById("Eid").value = inputValue.value
    
  }
)

 }
```

btw i'm using agilepoint - js and sweetalert2.

Thank you!